# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (11,) (10,) with quantile regression

Tags: python, statsmodels, quantile-regression

I'm trying to perform quantile regression using python statsmodels package.

I have 5 predictors along with 6 dummy variables that should be used to predict a variable FF159.

The problem is that the model works perfectly fine when I don't use one of the dummy variables alongside my predictors.
but when using all the 5 predictors alongside the 6 dummy variables it throws the error in title.

c1,c2,c3,c4,c5 and c6 are my dummy variables.

This code return the results below: (I only used 5 of my 6 dummy variables)

```
cv= pd.read_excel(directory2+'subset_data_after_FS_FF159.xlsx',  sheet_name = "Sheet1",index=False)
cv = cv.rename(columns={'1': 'c1', '2': 'c2','3': 'c3','4': 'c4','5': 'c5','6': 'c6'})
mod = smf.quantreg('FF159 ~ BO21+BO24+RE40+LA30+HORAIRE+c1+c2+c3+c4+c6', cv)
res = mod.fit(q=.7)
print(res.summary())
```

Results:

[image]

Using the 6 dummy variables alongside the predictors, python throws me this error:

[image]

I saw in some threads that it can be a multcollinearity problem but it's not.
The figure below shows my correlation matrix.

[image]

Comment: If your 6 dummy variables include all categories, then it will be perfectly linear with the constant. Correlation matrix will not show that because it is the sum of the dummy variables that is collinear to the constant. Check with np.linalg.matrix_rank.

Comment: @Josef Thank you for you anwser. Actually my 6 dummy variables represent a nominal variable with 6 categories. Removing one of the dummy variables from my data resolved the problem. I didn't know before that to create dummy variable you need to keep only n-1 of categories.

Comment: It's known as "dummy variable trap".